# How to use sed in order to search ^A and replace it

Tags: sed

I would like to use (GNU) sed to do a simple search and replace. The issue is that I'm searching for a special character and it might be the reason it failed for me.

The input is:

```
^A9=139^A35=V^A34=9^A49=xxxx^A52=20140527-06:18:43.759^A5
```

and I want to replace the `^A` with `;`. I used:

```
sed -i '/s/^A/;/g' file.log
```

but I didn't get anything.

Comment: Have you tried to escape the `^` with a backslash (\\)? Read http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/32907/what-characters-do-i-need-to-escape-when-using-sed-in-a-sh-script

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your command should be,

```
sed -i 's/\^A/;/g' file
```

Command you tried,

```
sed -i '/s/^A/;/g' file.log
        |  |
        |  |______________You have to escape this special character. Because in general(regex) it means the starting point.
[No need to use `/` before s]
```

Example:

```
$ sed 's/\^A/;/g' file
;9=139;35=V;34=9;49=xxxx;52=20140527-06:18:43.759;5
```

Comment: what would be your desired output?

Comment: 9=139;35=V;34=9;49=xxxx;52=20140527-06:18:43.759;5`

Comment: Then try `sed 's/\^A/;/g;s/ ;/ /g' file`. Use `i` option if you want to save the edit.

Comment: is that backticks are present inside your input?

Comment: now works! (=
can you please explain why i need all this long code?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54496/discussion-between-avinash-raj-and-assaf-baruch).

Comment: What do you mean? Did i have to explain my code? If yes, then which one? And don't forget to accept my answer.

Comment: Hi,
i want to learn from you hence i asked if you can please explain me your answer.

Answer (score 1):

^ has a special meaning with regular expressions. Use \^ (or potentially \\^, depending on how bash escapes things, I never quite remember it).